# Drag and Drop treeview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, treeview, parent-child

I know its kind of a new question but i really need that thing what i have research so far or what i have R&D on it ? i don't get any thing yet  that's really helps me so i think may be this thing work 
there is an app in android who have already implement this functionality its some sort of drag and drop tree-view 
Here is URL of this app 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.safetyculture.iauditor

[image: This is what i want]

**Major Question** what i have done so far to get this

I have try these libraries to get this thing done but i don't achieve anything with this
https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

https://github.com/fada21/HydraListAndroid

https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList

https://github.com/max-kammerer/orion-viewer/tree/master/tree-view-list-android

If any body can help me it will be appreciated i am in big trouble with this thing

Comment: Is that your trying to achieve drag and drop an item in list view or anything specific with tree view. Can you provide some more info?

Comment: i need drag drop but with treeview functionality to i mead to say in this list there will be parent child relationship like multiple inheritance and if its still not clear than go and download the sample application from google playstore than you will got clear picture

Comment: Asking people to download and run another application to find out what you meant is not likely to help get a good answer.

Comment: i know i already get the answer below answer really helps me in what i need and i have make my own code to get this but thank you for your consideration :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList
you can still use this library and create your own  listener i have studied this library
there is 100% possibility to achieve this.
And the other thing about treeView you can try this just split the screen touch in 2 sides left and right when user drag the item in left portion it will be added as parent or be on the right it will be child hope this will help you and give you success

Comment: So, did anybody have success with this one?